# Easiest way to export functions from a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I am migrating a bunch of changes from our dev database, consisting of some extra tables, the data from a subset of these tables, and some new functions. Using `phpmyadmin` I have exported the structure of the tables as an SQL file, and the data of the subset where I need it. However `phpmyadmin` offers no way to export the functions en-masse that I can see.

Am I missing a trick, or should I just be manually creating a .sql file containing each of the function definitions?

(I appreciate that in the time it's taken to type this question and wait for answers I can probably have done the latter, but it feels inelegant given how straightforward the first 2 SQL files were to create automatically!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check 'Add CREATE PROCEDURE / FUNCTION' in export page.

Comment: ARGH! How did I miss that? But, how do I select which functions I want to export? Is it clever enough to only do those that can relate to the tables being exported?